# no. of recordings per ten year period in pig

Tags: apache-pig, data-analysis

i have data like this

```
name, id, nametype,recclass,mass, fall, year,

Aachen,1, Valid,    L5,      21,  Fell, 01/01/1880 12:00:00 AM,

Aarhus,2, Valid,    H6,      720  Fell, 01/01/1951 12:00:00 AM

 :     :


 :     :

 :    45700
```

i have to find out no. of recordings per ten year period using piglatin. don't know start and end year as data not sorted

I tried following code:

```
nasadata = load 'Meteorite_Landings.csv' using PigStorage(',') as(name:chararray,id:int,nametype:chararray,recclass:chararray,mass:int,fall:chararray,year:chararray);

B = FOREACH nasadata  GENERATE year;

C = FOREACH B GENERATE ToDate(year,'dd-MM-YYYY') as year1;
```

when I dumped C it shows failed to read data from input file.but it worked when i dumped nasadata.when i describe C  it shows

```
C: {year1: datetime}
grunt>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the ToDate format is correct as "01/01/1880 12:00:00 AM" doesn't have the format 'dd-MM-YYYY', "01-01-1880" would however.

You could try formatting the date or use `STRSPLIT(STRSPLIT(year, ' ').$0, '/').$2` to extract the year. Then cast to an integer with `(INT)STRSPLIT(STRSPLIT(year, ' ').$0, '/').$2`. You could then round the year down to the nearest ten with something like.

```
A = FOREACH data GENERATE (INT)STRSPLIT(STRSPLIT(year, ' ').$0, '/').$2 AS year;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE (year - (year % 10)) AS year_rounded;
C = GROUP B BY year_rounded;
D = FOREACH C GENERATE group, COUNT(C):
```